# Vagrant cant provision vm with debian/bookworm64 ssh authentification failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, debian, vagrant

I am trying to start up a VM with this [box](https://app.vagrantup.com/debian/boxes/bookworm64) "debian/bookworm64" but it timeouts during the ssh authentification. I've used the same Vagrantfile with `ubuntu/focal64` and there it just works. I had no ssh authentification problem using the ubuntu:20.04 box, why with debian:12? But I can `vagrant ssh`into the VM after `vagrant up` timeouts. But the provision step of the Vagrantfile won't be started, which I need. I stumbled over this answer in this [debian thread](https://teams.debian.org/debian-cloud/2023/08/msg00005.html):

> Ubuntu 20.04 "jammy" has ruby-net-ssh 6.1.0. That version is unable to
> connect to recent OpenSSH, as found in Debian bookworm. In Debian
> bullseye, ruby-net-ssh was updated to version 1:6.1.0-2+deb11u1 to fix
> that. Probably the same update would be needed in Ubuntu.

This is the latest version released in Ubuntu:20.04:
`ruby-net-ssh is already the newest version (1:5.2.0-1)`. Could this be the problem? Does someone else had similiar issues with a the debian/bookworm64 box or a different one?

I already tried several approaches like checking that .ssh/authorized_keys is `chmod 0600` on the VM, also `.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key`is in the home path of the host machine. I mean `vagrant ssh` works, why does the ssh authentification not work when vagrant tries to provision the new VM?

Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.box = "debian/bookworm64"
  config.vm.hostname = "test02"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.name = "debian12"
    v.memory = 4096
    v.cpus = 2
  end
end
```

Error-Log:

```
D, [2023-11-07T18:03:35.124736 #896133] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3a9a8]: allowed methods: publickey
E, [2023-11-07T18:03:35.124763 #896133] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[3a9a8]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey)

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO ssh: SSH not ready: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHAuthenticationFailed: SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.>
```

further down the log:

```
If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay I finally solved it! I think the reason was `ruby-net-ssh` So we upgraded our server from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and `vagrant up` was finally running passed the ssh authentifation step to provision the VM